# TS errors not detected by eslint

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a nextJS app that uses typescript. I develop using VSCode. I noticed that VSCode displays TS errors as intended when I open a file with an error but `eslint` doesn't.

For example, here is my VSCode errors:

[image: VSCode TS error]

But here is my linting results:

```sh
▶ yarn lint

yarn run v1.22.10
$ eslint .
(node:83388) ExperimentalWarning: Conditional exports is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(node:83388) ExperimentalWarning: Package name self resolution is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
✨  Done in 5.26s.
```

Here are some files that might be useful to identify the problem:

.eslintrc.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  extends: [
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
  ],
  ignorePatterns: [
    'app.js',
    '.eslintrc.js',
    'jest.config.js',
    'babel.config.js',
    '/plugins',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  rules: {
    'react/require-default-props': ['warn', { ignoreFunctionalComponents: true }],
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.spec.tsx', '*.stories.tsx'],
      rules: {
        'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 'off',
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2016",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

bable.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      'next/babel',
      {
        'styled-jsx': {
          plugins: [path.join(__dirname, '/plugins/styled-jsx-plugin-sass.js')],
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  plugins: ['inline-react-svg']
}
```

package.json scripts:

```json
{
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx only-allow npm",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -s ./public -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "test": "jest"
  },
}
```

I'll be more than happy to provide any further information to help fix the problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After more research I found this github issue with the same problem: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/352

In which the answer was:

> we purposely do not care about errors that should arise as a result of type checking errors.
> We only care that the code is syntactically valid (i.e. can be parsed without errors), not about whether it's semantically valid (i.e. don't care if it is type sound)

> If you want your code to be typechecked - please use `tsc` (or one of the tools built for your specific build chain).

So the solution in my case was to edit my `lint` script to be:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tsc --noEmit && eslint .",
  },
}
```

The `--noEmit` flag tells the command to not generate any files.